# How to specify commandline arguments to a docker container in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: docker, arguments, containers, azure-service-fabric

I've a docker image [wiremock.net-nano](https://hub.docker.com/r/sheyenrath/wiremock.net-nano/) which accepts additional commandline parameters like `--Port` and `--AdminUsername`.

The normal docker commandline looks like:

```
docker run --rm -p 9091:80 sheyenrath/wiremock.net-nano --ReadStaticMappings true --AdminUsername x --AdminPassword y --RequestLogExpirationDuration 24
```

But how can I configure these parameters in **Azure Service Fabric**?

The *ServiceManifest.xml* file defines only the image name (`<ImageName>sheyenrath/wiremock.net-nano</ImageName>`) and port forwarding (`<Endpoint Name="WireMock_ContainerTypeEndpoint" Port="9091" />`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the `<ContainerHostEntryPointType>/<Commands>` in the element is what you are looking for.

As per `ServiceManifest.xml` [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-model-schema-complex-types#containerhostentrypointtype-complextype):

> Pass a comma delimited list of commands to the container.

The schema excerpt:

```
<xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric" name="ContainerHostEntryPointType">
<xs:sequence>
  <!--container image name-->
  <xs:element name="ImageName" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>The repo and image on https://hub.docker.com or Azure Container Registry.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <!--comma delimited list of commands for container-->
  <xs:element name="Commands" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Pass a comma delimited list of commands to the container.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="EntryPoint" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:element name="FromSource" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: This is indeed correct. Now I used this "<Commands>--AllowPartialMapping false,--x y</Commands>" 

However the problem is that the commandline parameters are passed with single quotes. Like '--AllowPartialMapping false'.

Comment: @StefHeyenrath were you able to pass parameters commands that needed to be in double quotes? I need to pass a command line argument:
-e "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret"

Comment: @JavaadPatel as far as I understand you are trying to set environment variables. If this is the case then according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#configure-and-set-environment-variables) you can set them in <CodePackage>/<EnvironmentVariables> node. Regarding <Commands> tag - as far as I understand it uses the same semantics and server the same purpose as docker [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) (but I am not 100% sure) instruction.

Comment: @OlegKarasik you are correct, I misunderstood the Docker syntax, the "-e" is as you say setting an environment variable. I changed my service manifest to pass these in and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

As Oleg has explained correctly, you have to specify your parameters in the ServiceManifest.xml alongside the container image name in the `<Commands>` element.

What gave me troubles was correctly passing an argument with its value(s). What I found out is Service Fabric will wrap your commands into double quotes if a whitespace is present. In this case you have to replace the whitespaces with commas.

For example, I have a custom Dockerfile with the following entrypoint definition in exec format:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["redis-server.exe", "C:\\Redis\\redis.docker.conf"]
```

I wanted to pass `--slaveof my-redis-master-instance 6379` as an argument to my docker container (where 6379 is the port of the master). The following service manifest would result in an error:

```
<EntryPoint>
  <ContainerHost>
    <ImageName>myrepository.azurecr.io/my.servicefabric.redis:3.</ImageName>
    <Commands>--slaveof my-redis-master-instance 6379</Commands>
  </ContainerHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

The reason is Service Fabric does wrap the command into quotes and then passes this to the docker image where it is interpreted as a single argument and causes an error.

Like already explained above, the solution is to replace the whitespaces with commas. Now Service Fabric passes the arguments separately.

```
<EntryPoint>
  <ContainerHost>
    <ImageName>myrepository.azurecr.io/my.servicefabric.redis:3.2.100</ImageName>
    <Commands>--slaveof,my-redis-master-instance,6379</Commands>
  </ContainerHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

For clarification, in my case I used Service Fabric for Windows with Containers based on Nanoserver 1803.

Comment: what container image are you using?

Comment: Windows. I'm not familiar with redis, and I just realized the above is for the commands to be run IN the container, right? I want to pass arguments to docker itself to set the MAC address of the container, but can't find a way. Maybe not possible.