# How to pass command line arguments to docker Grafana container in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, grafana

I'm trying to run grafana as a container inside my service fabric cluster. The container is healthy if I deploy without commmand line arguments, but when I try to pass command line arguments as shown below in the service manifest it fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="Grafana.Pkg"
                 Version="1.0.0"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ServiceTypes>
        <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="Grafana.Type" UseImplicitHost="true" />
    </ServiceTypes>

    <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
    <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
        <EntryPoint>
            <ContainerHost>
                <ImageName>myregistry.azurecr.io/grafana:6.3.2</ImageName>
        <Commands>-e "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://serverurl.com/grafana"</Commands>
            </ContainerHost>
        </EntryPoint>
    </CodePackage>

    <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0" />

    <Resources>
        <Endpoints>
            <Endpoint Name="Grafana.TypeEndpoint" UriScheme="http" Protocol="http" Port="3000" />
        </Endpoints>
    </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

The actual docker command for running grafana is shown below
[image]

specifically I need to pass

```
-e "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://grafana.server.name"
```

and

```
-e "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret"
```

What is the recommended way to pass command line arguments in the ServiceFabric manifest? Also is there a way to escape the double quotes that need to be passed in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify commandline arguments to a docker container in Azure Service Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668237/how-to-specify-commandline-arguments-to-a-docker-container-in-azure-service-fabr)

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks I've read that question/answer but it doesn't fully explain how one would pass a parameter that needed to be in double quotes like my situation, I've commented on the answer, and if I get a reply I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: escape the quotes?

Comment: from the unanswered comment on that answer, the commandline parameters are passed with single quotes. I am thinking that that this is causing an issue because I need the parameter (GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL) to be wrapped in double quotes. I'm not sure how to see the exact command line argument that is being passed into the container

Comment: log in to the node?

Comment: that's a good idea, i'll try login to the node now, any idea where I would find the log showing the command line argument passed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198032/discussion-between-javaadpatel-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-e` arguments for the [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) CLI, are environment variables to be set in the container. You can specify them in the [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#configure-and-set-environment-variables).

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
  ...
  <EnvironmentVariables>
    <EnvironmentVariable Name="GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL" Value="https://serverurl.com/grafana"/>    
  </EnvironmentVariables>
</CodePackage>
```